# Proof that the Fibonacci sequence grows exponentially

Tags: recurrence-relations, exponential-function, fibonacci-numbers

I wanted to write a proof similar to the one on page $3$ here ($2.2$ Fibonacci numbers):

http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/99-recurrences.pdf ,

to show that a sequence, defined with recurrence, grows exponentially. But I have some questions about this proof (also I kind of understand the idea but I don't known exactly what is the theory behind it..)

First (maybe this is just notation):  It says "..the other root of the quadratic equation has smaller absolute value, so we can ignore it.." and write:

\begin{equation}
F_n \leq \alpha \phi^n
\end{equation}
but it would not be possible to write it like that if $\phi$ was a complex number with imaginary part, Would it be then $F_n \leq \alpha |\phi|^n$?

Second: I don't get the fact that it is sufficient to use the base case (with an "$=$" sign?) to choose $\alpha$, it is not clear for me why it will then work with the third value for example.. or is that because we don't care for small $n$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: But the roots of the characteristic polynomial for the Fibonacci sequence are both real, so the issue does not arise.

Comment: Sorry, I meant can we use this proof in general, even if the root with the biggest absolute value has an imaginary part?

Comment: Sure.  If one root has bigger norm than the others, that one will eventually dominate the series.

Comment: So then you have to write $|\phi|$ because it doesn't mean anything to be smaller than a complex number?

Comment: Yes, you have to talk about the modulus of $\phi$ for complex numbers

Comment: Perfect thanks, I just wanted to be sure!

Comment: Worth noting that the Fibonacci case is special in another way:  only one root has norm $>1$ and the other have norm $<1$, making the big root a so-called [Pisot Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number).  That means that, eventually, you can ignore the other roots completely (as you know the value you want is an integer).  Greatly simplifies computations.

Comment: Ok, I thought the other roots where not important because if you for example had the two roots $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ with $\phi_1$ has bigger absolute value than $\phi_2$, you could write something like $F_n \leq \phi_1^n(\alpha+\beta \frac{\phi_2^n}{\phi_1^n})$ and that the $\frac{\phi_2^n}{\phi_1^n}$ will just go to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity..

Answer (score 0):

*It says "..the other root of the quadratic equation has smaller absolute value, so we can ignore it.." and write: Fn≤αϕn
but it would not be possible to write it like that if ϕ was a complex number with imaginary part, Would it be then Fn≤α|ϕ|n?*

The roots of $c^2-c-1$ are both real numbers, $c_1 = -0,61803399$ and $c_2 = 1,61803399$.

Comment: Yes I know, my question was if we can generalize it even if the biggest root is complex